# spread creates separate rows for variables tidyr

Tags: r, tidyr

I'm hoping someone can help me suss out what's wrong with my data here. I'm trying to convert several time-varying covariates from long into wide, seen below:

```
   dummy.data<-data.frame(ID=rep('ID1',10),var1=rep('A',10),age=seq(1,10,1),
                    var2=c(1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0),var3=seq(5,14,1))

    dummy.data%>%gather(age.var,value,-ID,-var1,-age)%>%
        unite(age.var,age.var,age)%>%
        spread(age.var,value)
```

but when I use a real data set,  a few observations cause spread to write each time-varying covariate into different rows, filling the other as an NA and I have no clue why:

```
    library(tidyverse)

real.data= structure(list(NestID = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("SwanA_17", 
"SwanC_17"), class = "factor"), detection = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1
), pred.fish = c(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), WA = c(208.8195728, 208.8195728, 
208.8195728, 208.8195728, 208.8195728, 208.8195728, 208.8195728, 
208.8195728, 208.8195728, 208.8195728, 208.8195728, 208.8195728, 
208.8195728, 208.8195728, 208.8195728, 208.8195728, 208.8195728, 
208.8195728, 208.8195728, 208.8195728, 208.8195728, 208.8195728, 
208.8195728, 208.8195728, 208.8195728, 208.8195728, 208.8195728, 
208.8195728, 208.8195728, 208.8195728, 208.8195728, 208.8195728, 
208.8195728, 208.8195728, 208.8195728, 208.8195728, 208.8195728, 
208.8195728, 208.8195728, 208.8195728, 208.8195728, 208.8195728, 
208.8195728, 208.8195728, 208.8195728, 208.8195728, 208.8195728, 
208.8195728, 208.8195728, 208.8195728, 208.8195728, 208.8195728, 
208.8195728, 208.8195728, 208.8195728, 208.8195728, 208.8195728, 
208.8195728, 208.8195728, 208.8195728, 208.8195728, 208.8195728, 
208.8195728, 208.8195728, 208.8195728, 208.8195728, 208.8195728, 
208.8195728), year = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), cdoy = c(-10, -9, -8, 
-7, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 
17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, -35, -34, 
-33, -32, -25, -24, -23, -22, -21, -20, -19, -18, -17, -16, -15, 
-14, -13, -12, -11, -10, -9, -8, -7, -6, -5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 
0, 1, 2, 3, 4), age = c("0", "1", "2", "3", "10", "11", "12", 
"13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", 
"24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31", "32", "33", "34", 
"35", "36", "37", "38", "39", "0", "1", "2", "3", "10", "11", 
"12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", 
"23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31", "32", "33", 
"34", "35", "36", "37", "38", "39"), known = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1
), unk = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), .Names = c("NestID", "detection", 
"pred.fish", "WA", "year", "cdoy", "age", "known", "unk"), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -68L))


gather(real.data,variable,value,c(detection,cdoy))%>%
        mutate(age=ifelse(nchar(age)<2,paste0('0',age),age))%>%
        unite(temp.var,variable,age)%>%
        spread(temp.var,value)
```

Comment: what would be the expected output ? (for me, the real dataset doesn't produce any NA)

Comment: that's odd. in mine it puts SwanA_17 on two lines. Guess I will check my packages for updates.

Comment: That is expected. Once line for 'Detection` and another line for `cdoy`. Isn't it?

Comment: no, the spread data should have one row for each Nest ID and the detection and cdoy are all in separate columns

Comment: ok. That means you just want to spread `temp.var` and 'value`? You can do that if you just have `NestID` and `temp.var` and 'value`. And then `inner_join` with `real.data`.

Comment: Ok, thanks, but why does it work for one level of NestID, but not the other?

Comment: You can try `dcast` as: `gather(real.data,variable,value,c(detection,cdoy))%>%
  mutate(age=ifelse(nchar(age)<2,paste0('0',age),age))%>%
  unite(temp.var,variable,age)%>%
  dcast(NestID+pred.fish+WA+year+known+unk~temp.var)`

Comment: I have already, and I get the same behavior

Comment: You should have got `2` rows and columns for all `detection` and `cdoy`. Isnt it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166603/discussion-between-tlyons253-and-mkr).

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, spread nor dcast can handle a numeric vector being an ID/left hand side of formula vector. Converting WA to something other than a floating numeric first (e.g., character, integer) produces the desired output.